# Anonymous on the entire site except for one page using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I would like to have anonymous access for an entire asp.net site except for one page.  On that one page, I would still like everyone to access the page but I would like to retrieve their username.  Here is what I have so far:

In the web.config, system.web section I am requesting windows authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
```

Then I am specifying the location that I would like to force windows authentication:

```
  <location path="forceWindowsAuth.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <!-- will deny anonymous users -->
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

However this is still not working.  It is denying everyone from viewing **forceWindowsAuth.aspx** with the message "**Access is Denied**"

The IIS site is configured for both anonymous and windows auth.  I just cannot figure out how to force windows auth on one page only.  Thank you before hand for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is whether you have seen "Allow all user" rule inherited from root level. As you can see I only have a deny rule for anonymous rule, but it will also inherit the allow all users rule. So it will promise only anonymous user will be blocked in this page and other user will not be blocked.

[image]

[image]

If there is only one "deny anonymous user", other user will never be able to view this page. If you don't set either deny or allow for a user, IIS will block the user by default.

**Edit:**

You can fix this by modifying the web.config like this.

```
<location path="forceWindowsAuth.aspx">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authorization>
                     <clear/>
                <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
                    <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
                </authorization>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

Comment: Jokies thank you for your answer!  Can this be done in the web.config without having to modify the IIS settings?  Basically I would like everyone to access "forceWindowsAuth.aspx"  (whether or not they are a windows user) and possibly retrieve their username if available.  All other pages would be completely anonymous.

Comment: @RobertSmith Sure,  you could modify this configuration like my post above. It will block inherit and use his own configuration.  You can modify this in the root web.config of your web application.